Add two new elements to a vector in a struct and link the new elements using one of their fields
Please consider the following playground for a minimal example of my problem learning the Rust language.
https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1024d918e3b7a9f5f139edf799ac5d47
mod class {
    use std::collections::HashMap;

    pub struct Friends {
        first_person_id : usize,
        second_person_id : usize
    }

    pub struct Person {
        external_id : usize,
        internal_id : usize,
        friends : Vec<Friends>
    }

    pub struct Class {
        persons: Vec<Person>,
        friends: Vec<Friends>,
        external_to_internal: HashMap<usize, usize>
    }

    impl Class {
        pub fn new() -> Class {
            Class{persons: vec![], friends: vec![], external_to_internal: HashMap::new()}
        }

        //If a person with the given name exists in self.persons, return a mutable reference to it.
        // Otherwise, add it and return a mutable reference to the new person that is now stored in the last position of self.persons.
        pub fn add_person(&mut self, external_id: usize) -> &mut Person {
            let id = self.external_to_internal.get(&external_id);
            return if id.is_none() {
                let internal_id = self.persons.len();
                self.persons.push(Person{external_id, internal_id, friends: vec![] });
                &mut *self.persons.last_mut().unwrap()
            } else {
                &mut self.persons[*id.unwrap()]
            }
        }

        pub fn add_friends(&mut self, external_one: usize, external_two: usize) {
            let person_one = self.add_person(external_one);
            let person_two = self.add_person(external_two);

            person_one.friends.push(Friends{first_person_id: person_one.internal_id, second_person_id: person_two.internal_id});
            person_two.friends.push(Friends{first_person_id: person_two.internal_id, second_person_id: person_one.internal_id});
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    use crate::class::*;
    let mut my_school_class = Class::new();
    my_school_class.add_friends(1234, 5678)
}


I'm trying to model a school class. It contains a vector of persons and a vector of friends. I model Friends as a pair of persons and store them in the 'Friends' struct using the persons' internal ids. A person has an external id (e.g. passport number), an internal_id that corresponds to its index in the vector of persons in the Class instance, and a vector of Friends.
My problem is related to the function 'Class::add_friends'. Its input the external ids of two persons. First, the function tries to get a reference to each of these two persons in the Class vector of Persons. If any of these perons does not yet exist, a new Person is created and pushed to the Class' vector of Persons. When both persons exist, I want to add  them to the list of friends of each other.
The compiler says that I'm borrowing 'self' more than once as a mutable reference and I understand why. But I have no idea how to achieve what I want in Rust. I'm strict about how the three structs in the example are defined. How can I write the "Class::add_friends" function without re-designing the structs?

Please add the example to the question itself, as Stack Overflow requires self contained questions.

Returning a &mut Person in .add_person() is a very constraining decision, since the Class is exclusively borrowed by the result of this function.
If you simply return the internal id of the created or accessed person, then you can do anything with this result: obtain a shared or exclusive reference to this person, depending on your intention.
The usage of this internal id is just the appropriate indexing operation, as it was done anyway in your version of add_person(), thus it does not cost more.
The add_friends() function can then be adjusted accordingly.
Note that you forgot to update the hashmap when a new person is created.
        pub fn add_person(
            &mut self,
            external_id: usize,
        ) -> usize {
            match self.external_to_internal.get(&external_id) {
                Some(id) => *id,
                None => {
                    let internal_id = self.persons.len();
                    self.external_to_internal
                        .insert(external_id, internal_id);
                    self.persons.push(Person {
                        external_id,
                        internal_id,
                        friends: vec![],
                    });
                    internal_id
                }
            }
        }

        pub fn add_friends(
            &mut self,
            external_one: usize,
            external_two: usize,
        ) {
            let person_one_id = self.add_person(external_one);
            let person_two_id = self.add_person(external_two);

            self.persons[person_one_id].friends.push(Friends {
                first_person_id: person_one_id,
                second_person_id: person_two_id,
            });
            self.persons[person_two_id].friends.push(Friends {
                first_person_id: person_two_id,
                second_person_id: person_one_id,
            });
        }

And if you don't want to expose the internal id in the public API, you can rename add_person() into add_person_id() and make it private (remove pub), and adjust add_friends() consequently.
Then, for the public API, you can provide the following function.
        pub fn add_person(
            &mut self,
            external_id: usize,
        ) -> &mut Person {
            let id = self.add_person_id(external_id);
            &mut self.persons[id]
        }


add_person() is useless, as it will still borrow the class mutably,

@ChayimFriedman Yes, I really still miss experience, because I don't see that immediately, thanks again for your help.

So, @ChayimFriedman do you have any suggestion on how to solve my design issue?

I mean: the code works now but from your comment I understand that this is bad style or bad practice in rust. I understand what's going on under the hood quite well; I now want to come up with a solution that teaches how to achieve this in an elegant way...

@ahul-fell-awen Sorry, I guess the remark was made because I initially proposed in the public API add_person(&mut self ...) -> &Person and add_person_mut(&mut self...) -> &mut Person, as I thought the distinction was useful. But Chayim noticed that the distinction was useless because even when obtaining a &Person this still borrows the &mut self with the same duration. Then I edited in order to remove the useless function (we can always implicitly decay the obtained &mut Person to &Person). This changes nothing to the remaining of the approach (returning the id).
